# Retrieve data from multiple many to many relationship within the same two tables using LINQ

Tags: linq, many-to-many

I have 4 tables:

1. Accounts
2. Photos
3. AccountPhotos (AccuntID, PhotoID) - Holds records of bought photos
   for each account
4. AccountFlagPhotos (AccountID, PhotoID) - Holds records of flagged
   photos for each account

Thus I have 2 many to many relationships between the same 2 tables, holding the same data but for different purposes.

I usually SELECT records in LINQ between many to many relationship tables as follows:

```
public IQueryable<Photo> GetByAccount(string username)
    {
        //Get the specific Account record
        Account myAccount = new UserDAL().GetByID(username);

        //Get all photos for that account (many to many)
        return myAccount.Photos.AsQueryable();
    }
```

The problem is that this time I have two many to many relationships between the same two tables. How can I determine in the code above from which table (table 3 or 4) I want to retrieve records from?

Comment: Manage to fix the problem with the help of a classmate.

In such case, one should navigate to the model diagram in VS, click one of the relationships and in properties window, note the name of the relationship in End1/End2 Navigation Properties

Comment: Cannot turn this to Answer due to reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to the **Entity Model**
2. Right click on the **relationship**
3. Select **Properties**
4. Use the **End2 Navigation Property**

*N.B.:*

From the diagram you can directly go to the **relationship properties** by selecting the relationship from the **Navigation Properties** of a particular table.

Comment: Thanks JEPAAB, didn't notice your answer when I posted my comment.